# How to cast varchar to datetime in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I need to cast a string to a datetime so i can compare it later.

The varchar that i have is like this format:

```
     29/11/2013 12:00:00 a.m.
```

And i need it to cast to:

```
     2013-11-29 00:00:00.000
```

Im using MSSQL Server 2012

Thx for all

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, have a look a [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928.aspx) for more information.

Here are some examples:

```
-- converting from DD-MM-YYYY
select CONVERT(datetime, '29/11/2013 12:00:00 AM', 103)

-- converting from MM-DD-YYYY
select CONVERT(datetime, '11/29/2013 12:00:00 AM', 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF Your date is of type varchar in the database then if you need to retrieve
then these cases arises::
case1:if your data is in the format of "dd-MM-yyyy"
then you need to use query as follows
Query::
select * from [yourTableName] where convert(datetime,YourDateColumn,103) between '2016-02-12'(yyyy-MM-dd) AND '2016-03-12'

case2:if your data is in the format of "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

then you need to use query as follows
Query::
select * from [yourTableName] where convert(datetime,YourDateColumn,105) between '2016-02-12'(yyyy-MM-dd) AND '2016-03-12'